# Mysql-> Group after rand()

Tags: mysql, random

I have the following table in Mysql

```
Name  Age   Group
```

---

```
 abel    7      A
 joe     6      A
 Rick    7      A
 Diana   5      B
 Billy   6      B
 Pat     5      B
```

I want to randomize the rows, but they should still remain grouped by the Group column.
For exmaple i want my result to look something like this.

```
 Name  Age   Group
```

---

```
 joe     6      A
 abel    7      A
 Rick    7      A
 Billy   6      B
 Pat     5      B
 Diana   5      B
```

What query should i use to get this result? The entire table should be randomised and then grouped by "Group" column.

Comment: `ORDER BY group` ?

Comment: Note that group is a reserved word, making it a poor choice as a column/table identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,age INT NOT NULL
,my_group CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('Abel',7,'A'),
('Joe',6,'A'),
('Rick',7,'A'),
('Diana',5,'B'),
('Billy',6,'B'),
('Pat',5,'B');

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY my_group,RAND();
+-------+-----+----------+
| name  | age | my_group |
+-------+-----+----------+
| Joe   |   6 | A        |
| Abel  |   7 | A        |
| Rick  |   7 | A        |
| Pat   |   5 | B        |
| Diana |   5 | B        |
| Billy |   6 | B        |
+-------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Thank You! this helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

What you describe in your question as GROUPing is more correctly described as sorting. This is a particular issue when talking about SQL databases where "GROUP" means something quite different and determines the scope of aggregation operations.

Indeed "group" is a reserved word in SQL, so although mysql and some other SQL databases can work around this, it is a poor choice as an attribute name.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY `group`
```

Using random values also has a lot of semantic confusion. A truly random number would have a different value every time it is retrieved - which would make any sorting impossible (and databases do a *lot* of sorting which is normally invisible to the user). As long as the implementation uses a finite time algorithm such as quicksort that shouldn't be a problem - but a bubble sort would never finish, and a merge sort could get very confused.

There are also *degrees* of randomness. There are different algorithms for generating random numbers. For encryption it's critical than the random numbers be evenly distributed and completely unpredictable - often these will use hardware events (sometimes even dedicated hardware) but I don't expect you would need that. But do you want the ordering to be repeatable across invocations?

```
 SELECT *
 FROM yourtable
 ORDER BY `group`, RAND()
```

...will give different results each time.

OTOH

```
SELECT
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY `group`, MD5(CONCAT(age, name, `group`))
```

...would give the results always sorted in the same order. While

```
SELECT
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY `group`, MD5(CONCAT(DATE(), age, name, `group`))
```

...will give different results on different days.

Comment: Thank you! SELECT *
 FROM yourtable
 ORDER BY `group`, RAND().This worked  and was what i was asking

Answer (score 0):

Do the random first then sort by column group.

```
select Name, Age, Group 
from (
 select *
 FROM yourtable
 order by RAND()
     ) t
order by Group
```

Comment: Who upvotes this stuff? The inner ordering is redundant.

Comment: The sub query is redundant, and there's unquoted reserved words.

Comment: the requirement is "The entire table should be randomised except column group". Pls try it yourself too.

Comment: Tested and working in sqlfiddle before I post anything.

Comment: Perhaps we have different definitions of 'working'. Hence the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table order by Group,rand()
```